# How to make stroke starts outside the button - android

Tags: android

I got a button and I have a stroke around it. But for some reason the stroke starts inside the button not outside. How to make it outside?As you can see part of the stroke is inside the button

[image]

My code of the shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke
    android:width="6dp"
    android:color="#39ffffff" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/black"/>
<margin
    android:bottom="@dimen/dp12"
    android:top="@dimen/dp12"
    android:right="@dimen/dp12"
    android:left="@dimen/dp12"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a stroke for the rectangle and in addition you've a margin. try removing the margin